# Rails 4.1 can't do the @user_friendship.save in the controller and returns an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi apparently cant save my work in rails 4.1 after adding the state machine gem and doing some more details like when you add someone in the friends i get an error in my controller the @user_friendship.save

this is the controller line
i got this error in my User_Friendships Controller and the line that contains the @user_friendship.save fails every time

```
def create
    if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
        @friend = User.where(profile_name: params[:user_friendship][:friend_id]).first
        @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
        @user_friendship.save
        flash[:success] = "You are now friends with #{@friend.full_name}"
        redirect_to profile_path(@friend)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Friend required"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

this is the error that occurs when i add to the user friendship

```
NoMethodError in UserFriendshipsController#create

protected method `around_validation' called for #<StateMachine::Machine:0x007fe631d43a68>

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"gPaCH/833buhbi53USaprtbmvFGjNCHE7RYY+DW071s=",
 "user_friendship"=>{"friend_id"=>"popo"},
 "commit"=>"Yes,
 Add friend"}
```

i am new in rails so can you please explain more so that i can undestand why this is happening and thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this patch, Till they fix it, it will work

```
config/initializers/state_machine_patch.rb

module StateMachine
  module Integrations
     module ActiveModel
        public :around_validation
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the fix it works properly but how did that patch made it work properly?

Comment: :around_validation was a protected method there, so somehow wasn't callable fromt he place it was getting called...
If you can see in the patch we only made it public.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the newest version of statemachine? If no, try the newest version of state machine.
https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/295